# Entity Framework: how to add an association, based on an existing property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, edmx-designer

I'm using the database-first approach while setting my first steps in Entity Framework. In my SQL Server database I have two tables, `Location` and `Area`.

Both have an `Id` column and the `Location` table already has an `AreadId` property. I would like to use this property for creating a one-to-many association between both tables (many `Location` entries for one `Area` entry), so I have created the following in my EDMX diagram using the EDMX-designer:

[image: EDMX diagram screenshot]

In the automatically generated `Location.cs` file, it looks as follows:

```
public partial class Location
{
    ...
    public int AreaId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Area Area { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to use the already existing property `Location.AreaId` as the foreign key. How can I do that, using EDMX-designer?

Please keep in mind that I can modify the EDMX diagram, but not the automatically generated `Location.cs` file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried with this approach? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/relationships?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: You don't really need both though; you can reference `Location.Area.Id` as the FK value. This is generally considered the better approach anyway.